# C++| using lambda function to check if instream is opened successfully

Tags: c++, lambda

I want to use lambda function to return a boolean value if the captured filestream returns a failbit (`fs.fail() == nullptr`).

I tested with the normal controlflow and the stream does open successfully for extraction. However, the similar code with lambda function doesn't seem to work. How come?

```
const std::string RATE = "data/list.csv";

void lambdaTest() {
  static std::fstream fs;
  fs.open(RATE, std::ios::in);

  /* check whether the filestream was opened successfully */
  if (fs.fail()) {
    std::cout << "\nFAILD TO OPEN." << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << "\nINSTREAM READY." << std::endl;
  }
  
  /* lambda version: */
  if ([&]() { return fs.fail(); } ()) { std::cout << "FAILED TO OPEN." << std::endl; }
  else { std::cout << "INSTREAM READY." << std::endl; }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if (fs.fail()) return true; else return false;` ?

Comment: You can just `return !fs.fail();` in your lambda function to have the same logic. Not sure if that's what you intended.

Comment: You both are right. I overthought it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the opening failed. Then

```
if (fs.fail()) return false;
```

will be `false`. The lambda will return `false`, and your condition won't be true, and won't print that the opening failed.

You can change the lambda to

```
[&]() { return fs.fail()); }
```